# Any significance to name of class derived from HttpApplication in Global.asax.cs?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, global-asax

After creating an empty Web Application project (with both MVC and Web API checked), I noticed that the name of the class derived from HttpApplication in Global.asax.cs was "Global" rather than the usual "MvcApplication" that's used when creating a populated MVC project.

Other than ensuring that Global.asax references the name correctly, is there any signficance to the name itself, or can I change it if "Global" annoys me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there shouldn't be usually we care more about the Type of the object/class than it's name, but the best way to find out would be to change it and see.

Comment: Yes, I tested it on an empty project and it compiled and ran okay, but that's not to say there aren't gotchas lurking.  Just wanted to be sure I wasn't creating an issue.

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter. In fact, at runtime, if you call GetType().Name on the HttpApplication instance, the type name is just "global_asax".